# 1 year old bearded dragon problem - he is getting stressed by his own reflection

Tags: behavior, reptiles, containment, bearded-dragon, terrariums

I have a 1 yo bearded dragon. I have always used a 100 watt basking lightbulb for my 40 gallon (150 L) tank. He is just now starting to notice his reflection. I have the static background around 3 of the 4 glass sides of the tank; I also have plants around to minimize, but he will go behind the hanging plants and just press his body to glass. He also gets stressed with his black beard and waves, also does the head bobbing. I'm worrying; please help.

Comment: I do not know bearded dragons, I have a turtle. May it be an option, that it presses to the glas to cool down its temperature? For my turtle the baskinglight does warm up one spot, so the turtle can choose thw temperature it likes most